# Python/lxml/xpath for parsing Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, yahoo-finance

EDIT: I have provided the EXACT source code I'm using to try to figure out this issue.

I'm trying to extract the data on "total assets" from Yahoo Finance using Python 2.7 and lxml.  An example of a page I'm trying to extract this information from is **http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=FAST+Balance+Sheet&annual** .

I've already successfully extracted the data on "total assets" from Smartmoney.  An example of a Smartmoney page I'm able to parse is **http://www.smartmoney.com/quote/FAST/?story=financials&timewindow=1&opt=YB&isFinprint=1&framework.view=smi_emptyView** .

Here is a special test script I set up to work on this issue:

```
    import urllib
    import lxml
    import lxml.html 

    url_local1 = "http://www.smartmoney.com/quote/FAST/?story=financials&timewindow=1&opt=YB&isFinprint=1&framework.view=smi_emptyView" 
    result1 = urllib.urlopen(url_local1)
    element_html1 = result1.read()
    doc1 = lxml.html.document_fromstring (element_html1)
    list_row1 = doc1.xpath(u'.//th[div[text()="Total Assets"]]/following-sibling::td/text()')
    print list_row1

    url_local2 = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=FAST" 
    result2 = urllib.urlopen(url_local2)
    element_html2 = result2.read()
    doc2 = lxml.html.document_fromstring (element_html2)
    list_row2 = doc2.xpath(u'.//td[strong[text()="Total Assets"]]/following-sibling::td/strong/text()')
    print list_row2
```

I'm able to get the row of data on total assets from the Smartmoney page, but I get just an empty list when I try to parse the Yahoo Finance page.

The source code of the table row on the Smartmoney page is:

```
    <tr class="odd bold">
<th><div style='font-weight:bold'>Total Assets</div></th>
<td>  1,684,948</td>
<td>  1,468,283</td>                                
<td>  1,327,358</td>                                
<td>  1,304,149</td>                                    
<td>  1,163,061</td>
    </tr>
```

The source code of the table row on the Yahoo page is:

```
    <tr>
<td colspan="2"><strong>Total Assets</strong></td>
<td align="right"><strong>1,684,948&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></td>
<td align="right"><strong>1,468,283&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></td>
<td align="right"><strong>1,327,358&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contains syntax errors, should be `td/strong/text()` at the end, plus you have a trailing `]`.  I'd say that the correct query would be:

```
xpath('//td[strong[text()="Total Assets"]]/following-sibling::td/strong/text()')
```

Result:

```
>>> tree.xpath('//td[strong[text()="Total Assets"]]/following-sibling::td/strong/text()')
[u'1,684,948\xa0\xa0', u'1,468,283\xa0\xa0', u'1,327,358\xa0\xa0']
```

In the original page the "Total Assets" `<strong>` container has whitespace and linebreaks. Use the additional `normalize-space` function on the `text()` result like so:

```
xpath('//td[strong[normalize-space(text())="Total Assets"]]/following-sibling::td/strong/text()')
```

Comment: Your suggested command gives me no error, but it produces no results either - just '[]'.

Comment: soulseekah, I just edited my question to provide a script to cut, paste, and run.  This should make it easier for you and others to see what I'm doing wrong and to see if your solution works.

Comment: doc2.xpath('//td[strong[text()="Total Assets"]]/following-sibling::td/strong/text()') does not work.  It still leads to an empty list.

Comment: Ah, I know what the issue is! The `text()` is not `"Total Assets"` as you give in the example at all, the original page contains line breaks and whitespace!

Comment: Thanks, soulseekah!  I overlooked the white space.  For the benefit of anyone with the same issue, here is the xpath code that worked:
doc.xpath(u'.//th[div[contains (text(), "Total Assets")]]/following-sibling::td/text()')